# uploading video on Youtube using Request and Youtube Api

Tags: c#, upload, youtube-api

I created two programs which upload with different ways.. A few days ago both of them was working.. but not I dont know what happened they dont work

first is

```
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            string response = client.UploadString("https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin",
               string.Format("Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=youtube&source=YouTube.Library",
                   username, password));
```

I get 403 error code and no more information

second I use youtube api 2.0 and when I want to upload a video I get this error

The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Code is here

```
        Video newVideo = new Video();
        newVideo.Title = "denemeeeeeee";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "education, funny deneme";
        newVideo.Description = "bilgi mi istiyorsun";
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
         YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));


        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\file2.flv",
          "video/quicktime");
        Video createdVideo = Request.Upload(newVideo);
```

I used two developer keys and results are same.. I dont know where is the problem? Maybe youtube has changed something? Because it was working a few days ago..

And I thought that my developer account has blocked for any reason? I dont know whata are conditions .. Because my program is public and people can use how they want. I cant check them... in the other way, I created second google account and created a developer key and I tried it, the result is same.. my friends cant use my program because of that..